# Grouping certain rows with data on a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, grouping, window-functions

There is such a table of operations:

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| id | oper_date  | parent_id | amount |               p1                |               p2                |               p3                |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | 01.09.2018 |         1 |      5 | p1 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  2 | 01.09.2018 |           |      2 | p1 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  3 | 02.09.2018 |         1 |      7 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  4 | 02.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  5 | 02.09.2018 |           |      6 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  6 | 02.09.2018 |           |     10 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  7 | 03.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  8 | 03.09.2018 |         1 |      3 | p1 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  9 | 03.09.2018 |           |      2 | p1 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
| 10 | 04.09.2018 |           |      6 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 11 | 04.09.2018 |         1 |      7 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 12 | 04.09.2018 |           |     11 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 13 | 04.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 14 | 05.09.2018 |           |      8 | p1 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 05.09.2018 |
| 15 | 05.09.2018 |         1 |      2 | p1 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 05.09.2018 |
| 16 | 05.09.2018 |           |      6 | p1 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 05.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 05.09.2018 |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

When fetching rows whose `oper_date` is <= a specific date, it is necessary for
several rows with the same non-null value of the `parent_id` field
to display in the `amount` field the sum of all operations on that date.

In the fields `p1/p2/p3/id/oper_date`, I need to display the values of these fields on this date.

For example, if I select rows with `oper_date` <= 04.09.2018, I need to display this result:

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| id | oper_date  | parent_id | amount |               p1                |               p2                |               p3                |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|  2 | 01.09.2018 |           |      2 | p1 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 01.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  4 | 02.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  5 | 02.09.2018 |           |      6 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  6 | 02.09.2018 |           |     10 | p1 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 02.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  7 | 03.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
|  9 | 03.09.2018 |           |      2 | p1 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 03.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 01.09.2018 |
| 10 | 04.09.2018 |           |      6 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 11 | 04.09.2018 |         1 |     22 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 12 | 04.09.2018 |           |     11 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
| 13 | 04.09.2018 |           |      4 | p1 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p2 value at the date 04.09.2018 | p3 value at the date 04.09.2018 |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

For the row with `id` = 11, the field `AMOUNT` displays the sum (22=5+7+3+7) of the values
of all rows for which `parent_id` = 1 whose `oper_date` is <= 04/09/2018.

How to do this using sql-query?

P.S. When designing table, for a parent row in the parent_id field, I can either keep null or its id.

Comment: So you're looking for the sum of amounts corresponding to non-NULL parent_id for all dates whose oper_date is less than 04/09/2018, and for 04/09/2018 you want the sum of amounts where the parent_id = 1?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the logic with the parent_id and what is the value for p1, p2, p3? Is really part of the problem or can be removed for simplicity?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why row 11 get a group sum but for row 1 just disappear ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you've saved your date of interest (04/09/2018 in this case) as `@SetDate`. Going by your expected output, I'm guessing you want all those records that have a NULL `parent_id` on or before your `@SetDate`, and specifically for your `@SetDate` to be returned, and you want the sum of all amounts on and before your `@SetDate` where `parent_id` is not NULL as a separate record.

```
SELECT id, oper_date, parent_id, amount, p1, p2, p3
FROM your_table 
WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND oper_date <= @SetDate

UNION

SELECT 
(SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE oper_date = @SetDate AND parent_id = 1 LIMIT 1) AS id, 
@SetDate AS oper_date, 
1 AS parent_id, 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM your_table WHERE oper_date <= @SetDate AND parent_id = 1) AS amount,
(SELECT p1 FROM your_table WHERE oper_date = @SetDate AND parent_id = 1 LIMIT 1) AS p1,
(SELECT p2 FROM your_table WHERE oper_date = @SetDate AND parent_id = 1 LIMIT 1) AS p2,
(SELECT p3 FROM your_table WHERE oper_date = @SetDate AND parent_id = 1 LIMIT 1) AS p3
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytic Function Partition by will be helpful here. Using Order By ID will make sum progressive and max id will have sum of amount. Following should be working as you explained

WITH MY_VIEW AS
  (SELECT id, oper_date, parent_id, SUM(amount) over (partition BY parent_id order by id ) AS amount, p1, p2, p3
  FROM my_table
  WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL AND oper_date <= 
  )
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW WHERE id =
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM MY_VIEW
  )
  union

SELECT id, oper_date, parent_id, amount, p1, p2, p3
  FROM my_table
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND oper_date <=  
  order by id